# function returns a closure which return a closure that use the environment variable

Tags: rust

`functionA` returns `closureA`, and that `closureA` returns a `closureB`, `closureB` which use variable from `functionA`'s surrounding environment.

```
fn main () {
   type Closure1 = Box<Fn() -> ()>;
   type Closure2 = Box<Fn() -> Closure1>;

   fn closure_container() -> Closure2 {
       let mut a: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
       let closure2: Closure2 = Box::new(move || {
           let closure1 = || {
               println!("{}", a)
           };
           Box::new(closure1)
       });

       closure2
   }
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure
 --> src/main.rs:9:27
  |
6 |        let mut a: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
  |            ----- captured outer variable
...
9 |            let closure1 = move || {
  |                           ^^^^^^^ cannot move out of captured outer variable in an `Fn` closure
```

It compiles `let mut a = 100;`, But `let mut a: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();` will report a error! I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Actually, the error message does **not** suggest to add `move` in front of the closure…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have (rightly) used `move` for the first closure (line 7), but you need to also add it for the second closure (line 8):

```
let closure2: Closure2 = Box::new(move || {
    let closure1 = move || { // <-- Add "move" on this line
        println!("{}", a)
    };
    Box::new(closure1)
});
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=31dec3c9b2ff273ff0c4334e120f2642&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

This makes it work if `a` has a `Copy` type, but it causes the error `cannot move out of captured outer variable in an 'Fn' closure` when `a` is not `Copy` (eg if `a` is a `Vec`). The problem is due to the fact that you are defining `closure2` as `Fn`, which means that you are telling the compiler that you might want to call it more than once. However the first time you call `closure2` will move `a` into the returned `closure1`, so `a` won't be available for a possible next call to `closure2`.

Long story short: you need to define `closure2` as `FnOnce` to tell the compiler that you can't call it more than once, or you need to move a clone of `a` into `closure1` so that `closure2` will keep its copy.

#### Solution 1: `FnOnce`

```
type Closure1 = Box<Fn() -> ()>;
type Closure2 = Box<FnOnce() -> Closure1>;

fn closure_container() -> Closure2 {
    let a: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
    let closure2: Closure2 = Box::new(move || {
        let closure1 = move || {
            println!("{:?}", a)
        };
        Box::new(closure1)
    });

    closure2
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=a56f4b9e57e61a94fd7f74e400b9bba4&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Note however that although you can *create* a `Closure2` this way, it is impossible to *call* it in current stable Rust. If you are willing to use nightly, it should work if you replace `FnOnce` with [`FnBox`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/trait.FnBox.html), but I'm hitting another error with this ([playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=71f039bb06194aa2ef345787901aed45&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015)). For the time being, you will need to use solution 2 and clone `a`. If you want to avoid the cost of cloning the entire vector, you can [wrap it in an `Rc` and clone that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52603407/5397009) ([playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=ee8c8f2312e03d520b26ce8bf4560a03&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)).

#### Solution 2: Clone

```
type Closure1 = Box<Fn() -> ()>;
type Closure2 = Box<Fn() -> Closure1>;

fn closure_container() -> Closure2 {
    let a: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();
    let closure2: Closure2 = Box::new(move || {
        let b = a.clone();
        let closure1 = move || {
            println!("{:?}", b)
        };
        Box::new(closure1)
    });

    closure2
}
```

[playground](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=a69b26cf705c92e61fecb9f16db6b1ef&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: Yes! I edit the question, and the example now reproduces the problem I am facing to.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: [Solution 1](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=056202533bf21cdf235d84a1cc4c8698&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)  will report an error, when calling it. I'm kind confusing of the relationship between keyword `move` and trait `FnOnce`.

Comment: @周汉成 You're right, there is apparently a limitation in current rust that [makes it impossible to call a `Box<FnOnce>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/boxed/trait.FnBox.html). I'll add a note.